# Why cant I find where to download my distribution certificate?

Tags: xcode, certificate, distribution

As seen in this page: http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/distribution/index.action, under the "Create and download your iOS Distribution Provisioning Profile for App Store Distribution" it says:

1.Team Agents should navigate to the Provisioning section of the Provisioning Portal and select the Distribution tab.
2.Select the App Store radio button.
3.Enter the name for your Distribution P...

And it shows an image with that page, but when i follow the steps i end in the same "page", but it doesnt have the same items that the image!!, i dont know why i cant download the distribution certificate... (this page, instead of "create iphone distribution provisioning profile" and all it items, it says me: "App Store, Logo Licensing, and Affiliate Program, Visit the App Store Resource Center for information about the App Store, Logo Licensing, and the iTunes Affiliate Program." and thats all!...)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to "Provisioning", "Distribution" tab and there is a download button -- if you have created a distribution profile.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your role as a team member here:
http://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action#allpeople.

Do you have the necessary permission?  If your trying to create a profile but you are a "member", you would need to be an agent or admin.

Roles explained here:
http://developer.apple.com/programs/roles/index.php

See also: [Member Center User Management Help Document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#recipes/MemberCenter_Recipes/_index.html)

Comment: how do i check which is the role of this account?